# Binary not seen on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I want to upload a new build for an existing app. I archive in Xcode and upload using Xcode (did try Application Loader as well, same result). The upload works without errors and displays the green checkmark.
When I go to iTunes Connect now I do not see a new Build available. If I try to upload that build again I get a redundant binary error.

For testing I created a new app in iTunes Connect and tried to upload a build with the same result. Upload without errors but build simply not visible in iTunes Connect. There is no activity in the activity tab.

The first "missing build" was uploaded last week.

Does anybody have the same problem or have an idea on what to try or who to contact?

Comment: check your email registered with itunesconnect, there might be an email from apple with build rejection reason

Comment: Thanks @AmodGokhale